# Is it possible to delete MODE_PRIVATE Android SharedPreferences from another activity?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have two activities, HomePageActivity (home page) ListActivity (list of data), the datas of the ListActivity come from SharedPreferences. I would like to delete the SharedPreferences of ListActivity from the HomePageActivity (for example to resynchronize local data with remote data). Is it possible to do that from the HomePageActivity?

Here is the way the data are stored in SharedPreferences in ListActivity:

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
prefsEditor.putString(AppUser.SHARED_MYLIST, myList);
prefsEditor.apply();
```

And I would like to be able to remove these data from HomePageActivity.

Comment: If it's the same app then yes, preferences aren't activity specific unless you name your preference files in that manner. Are you getting an error or did you not try it out? https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
getPreferences("myPrefsName", MODE_PRIVATE)
```

in both your activities. You will get the same SharedPreferences instance.

Comment: I have no getPreferences method that take string and an int, I think that you are talking about `getSharedPreferences` however it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extend AppCompatActivity{
      protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            SharedPreferences mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
            prefsEditor.putString(AppUser.SHARED_MYLIST, myList);
            prefsEditor.apply();
      }
}


public class MainActivity2 extend AppCompatActivity{
      protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            SharedPreferences mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
            prefsEditor.remove(AppUser.SHARED_MYLIST).apply();
      }
}
```

Comment: I have tried it and it doesn't work... However when I try to delete the pref from MainActivity it works